# How to get the label specified in spring retryable annotation at class level in a MethodInvocationRetryListenerSupport?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

I have specified a @Retryable annotation in a spring bean like below.

```
@EnableRetry
@Import({GrpcClientRetryConfig.class})
@Retryable(interceptor = "grpcClientRetryInterceptor", label = "ProfileGrpcClient")
public class ProfileGrpcClient {
  public RateLimitConfig getRateLimitConfig()
```

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RateLimits {
  private final ProfileGrpcClient client;

  // Some method calls client.getRateLimitConfig()
}
```

Interceptor is defined in `GrpcClientRetryConfig`

```
@EnableRetry
public class GrpcClientRetryConfig {
 @Bean
 public RetryOperationsInterceptor grpcClientRetryInterceptor() {
    val template = new RetryTemplate();
    val backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    // Set the exponential backoff parameter
    val interceptor = new RetryOperationsInterceptor();
    template.setRetryPolicy(new SimpleRetryPolicy());
    template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
    template.setListeners(new GrpcClientRetryListener[] {new GrpcClientRetryListener()});
    interceptor.setRetryOperations(template);
    return interceptor;
 }
}
```

In `GrpcClientRetryListener` I am trying to get the label specified in the `@Retryable`

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class GrpcClientRetryListener extends MethodInvocationRetryListenerSupport {

  @Override
  public <T, E extends Throwable> void onSuccess(
      RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, T result) {
    if (callback instanceof MethodInvocationRetryCallback<T, E> methodInvocationRetryCallback) {
      log.info(
          "Retry Succeeded: {}, Count: {}",
          getMethodName(methodInvocationRetryCallback),
          context.getRetryCount());
    }
    super.onSuccess(context, callback, result);
  }

  @Override
  public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(
      RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
    if (callback instanceof MethodInvocationRetryCallback<T, E> methodInvocationRetryCallback) {
      log.info(
          "Retry Failing: {}, Count: {}",
          getMethodName(methodInvocationRetryCallback),
          context.getRetryCount());
    }
    super.onError(context, callback, throwable);
  }

  private <T, E extends Throwable> String getMethodName(
      MethodInvocationRetryCallback<T, E> methodInvocationRetryCallback) {
    return methodInvocationRetryCallback.getLabel();
  }
}
```

But during retry, I am seeing getting the label like `public com.abc.proto.v2.common.ratelimit.RateLimits com.abc.grpcclients.ProfileGrpcClient.getRateLimitConfig()`. Complete log is like below

```
Retry Failing: public com.abc.proto.v2.common.ratelimit.RateLimits com.abc.grpcclients.ProfileGrpcClient.getRateLimitConfig(), Count: 5
```

Is there a way for me to get the `label` as specified in `@Retryable` in `MethodInvocationRetryListenerSupport`?